# How to ask for y/n input with 'read -p' after 'eval' in ZSH?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, zsh

I want to write a ZSH function that suggests me to use `yadm push` after an erroneous `git push`.
I have set `alias git="correct git"` and the following function:

```
function correct (){
    if [ "$1" = "git" ] && [ "$2" = "push" ]; then
        eval "command $1 $2" ||
        echo "Try yadm?"
        select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
            case $yn in
                Yes ) yadm $2; break;;
                No ) break;;
            esac
        done
    fi
}
```

The above works as expected, while I fail doing the same with `read -p`:

```
function correct (){
    if [ "$1" = "git" ] && [ "$2" = "push" ]; then
        eval "command $1 $2" || 
        while true; do
            read -p "Try yadm? (y/n)" yn
            case $yn in
                [Yy]* ) yadm $2; break;;
                [Nn]* ) break;;
                * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
            esac
        done
    fi
}
```

How would one use `read -p` after an `eval` statement?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this it's not related to the use of eval at all. In ZSH, `read -p` wants to read from a coprocess instead of indicating the prompt. Answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198372/read-command-in-zsh-throws-error).

```
function correct (){
    if [ "$1" = "git" ] && [ "$2" = "push" ]; then
        command $1 $2 ||
        while true; do
            printf "Try yadm? (y/n)"
            read yn
            case $yn in
                [Yy]* ) yadm $2; break;;
                [Nn]* ) break;;
                * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
            esac
        done
    fi
}
```

Second line in both versions should be `command $1 $2 ||` to avoid  the use of `eval`, even though it should be sane inside the if statement.

Consulting `man zshbuiltins` would have been helpful.